# Hirearchial Data Template RadTreeView issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to  bind data to radtreeview through Hireachical Data Template. With Wpf treeview Its working. We wanted to change that to Radtreeview. When i am trying to achieve the same i am not getting that.

```
<TreeView  Name="treeview2" 


  Grid.RowSpan="2" Tag=""
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchTreeViewItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cluster}" Width="250" Height="251" Margin="0,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock  Padding="15,0,30,0" Text="{Binding Path=numitems}" TextAlignment="Right"  DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Text}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" TextAlignment="Left">
                     <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                  <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Rename" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Exlcude"/>

                   </ContextMenu>
</TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock> 
            </DockPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

I am looking for a sample which shows that bind a property. Cluster is a observablecollection property of type a class. Nodes is a child collection with in that. I am looking for transforming the same code to radtreeview-- Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you change to RadTreeView? There should be no difference.

Comment: Where is the `DataTemplate` for Type `Nodes`?

Comment: I am using Hirearchial Data Template right? nmaait I am trying to use the same but it is not able to find nodes

Comment: You may need to define a DataTemplate for Nodes.